# Groovy binding of keyword argument

Tags: binding, groovy, keyword-argument

The following code will produce an assertion error

```
def foo(a,b,c='awesome',d=null) {
    assert d
}

foo(1,2,d='bar')
```

Why does it give an error? Why is the keyword assignment of d not working? I find this very different from Python keyword argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groovy doesn't do keyword arguments quite the same as python.

First, the syntax is map-like.  Instead of

```
foo(1,2,d='bar')
```

you need

```
foo(1,2,d:'bar')
```

Second, groovy can't map the arguments to keywords by name.  A way to accomplish this in groovy is to accept the keyword arguments as a map:

```
def foo(Map kwargs, a, b, c='awesome') { [a,b,c,kwargs.d] }
assert foo(1,2,d:'bar') == [1,2,'awesome','bar']
```

More details on how groovy handles this is here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Extended+Guide+to+Method+Signatures.

Comment: [Archive.org link to the Extended Guide to Method Signatures](https://web.archive.org/web/20121204065939/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Extended+Guide+to+Method+Signatures) mentioned above. Thanks for the explanation @ataylor!